# Having trouble with one exercise from Kochan Book: Programming in C i + j - i % j

Tags: c

this is my source C code:

> details that stackoverflow want to see or i can't edit

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int  i, j;

    int Next_multiple = (i + j) - (i % j);

    i = 365;
    j = 7;

    printf("Solution for i == 365 j == 7 = %i \n", Next_multiple);

    i = 12258;
    j = 23;

    printf("Solution for i == 12258 j == 23 = %i \n", Next_multiple);

    i = 996;
    j = 4;

    printf("Solution for i== 996 j == 4 = %i \n", Next_multiple);

    return 0;
}
```

and that's the output:

.exe (Windows cmd within Visual studio tools)

```
Solution for i == 365 j == 7 = 18039659

Solution for i == 12258 j == 23 = 18039659

Solution for i== 996 j == 4 = 18039659
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: `Next_multiple` is computed only once (with uninitialized vars -> UB), better to turn it into a function.

Comment: `int Next_multiple = (i + j) - (i % j);` --> `#define Next_multiple  (i + j) - (i % j)`

Comment: Ok, i solved, thanks user3121023 and Jarod42 too. And other will answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have an undefined behaviour as you use uninitialised local variables i and j.

Then you display 3 times the same calculated (using those random values) variable.  How to sort it out?

1 place this function before the main.

```
  int Next_multiple(int i, int j)
  {
     return ( i + j) - (i % j);
   }
```

Change

```
printf("Solution for i == 12258 j == 23 = %i \n", Next_multiple);
```

To

```
  printf("Solution for i == 12258 j == 23 = %i \n", Next_multiple(i, j));
```

And remove

```
 int Next_multiple = (i + j) - (i % j);
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Next_multiple(int i, int j)
{
   return ( i + j) - (i % j);
}
int main () {

    int  i, j;

    i = 365;
    j = 7;

    printf("Solution for i == 365 j == 7 = %i \n", Next_multiple(i,j));

    i = 12258;
    j = 23;

    printf("Solution for i == 12258 j == 23 = %i \n", Next_multiple(i,j));

    i = 996;
    j = 4;

    printf("Solution for i== 996 j == 4 = %i \n", Next_multiple(i,j));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's another good way to resolve, but unfortunately output says "i" and "j" are not declared. it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is you compute `Next_Multiple` **before** you set the values of `i` and `j`.  You should instead write this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int i, j, Next_Multiple;

    i = 365;
    j = 7;
    Next_multiple = (i + j) - (i % j);

    printf("Solution for i = 365, j = 7 -> %i\n", Next_multiple);

    i = 12258;
    j = 23;
    Next_multiple = (i + j) - (i % j);

    printf("Solution for i = 12258, j = 23 -> %i\n", Next_multiple);

    i = 996;
    j = 4;
    Next_multiple = (i + j) - (i % j);

    printf("Solution for i = 996, j = 4 -> %i\n", Next_multiple);

    return 0;
}
```